# Storing Swift value types in Core Data

Tags: swift, cocoa, core-data, swift2

Is there a way to `store` Swift's `value` types, such as `enums` or `structs` in Core Data?

What's the best way of doing this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy: Just initialise `NSData` with the bytes of your value type.

Your value type:

```
struct MyStruct {
    let x : Int
    let y : Bool
    let z : Double
}
```

Functions to set and get the data

```
func valueToData<T>(var t: T) -> NSData {
    return NSData(bytes: &t, length: sizeof(T))
}

func dataToValue<T>(inout t: T, data: NSData) {
    memcpy(&t, data.bytes, data.length)
}
```

Tests:

```
let originalValue = MyStruct(x: 3, y: true, z: 1.3)

let data = valueToData(originalValue)

// Save data to CoreData

var s = MyStruct(x: 0, y: false, z: 0)  // Empty Value
dataToValue(&s, data: data) // Initialize with data

// s is MyStruct(x: 3, y: true, z: 1.3)
```

Answer (score 1):

A suitable way for `enum` is to declare the enum with a raw type supported by Core Data and use a custom instance property to convert the enum case to raw value and vice versa.

For example:

```
enum State : Int32 {
  case None, Empty, Full
}

@NSManaged var state: Int32

var stateEnum: State {
  get {
    return State(rawValue: state)!
  }
  set {
    state = newValue.rawValue
  }
}
```

A `struct` has to be "serialized" in a similar way – maybe it could be even represented by an Core Data entity – but this depends on the struct(ure) of the struct.